# SQL Math function in 3 joined Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have question about SQL query

I have similary this tables

TABLE1:

```
id_table1    ean    date_from      date_to     type     region   town_id     consumption 
  1          1234   2020-01-01    2021-01-01   blue      big       100        20000
  2          5678   2020-01-01    2021-01-01   blue      big2      200        80000
  2          6845   2020-01-01    2021-01-01   white    small      300        10000
```

TABLE2:

```
id_table2        day          type_blue_big_coefficient   type_blue_big2_coefficient  type_white_coefficient
  1          2020-01-01                 0.011120                0.32652                     0.054165
  2          2020-01-01                 0.023265                0.12543                     0.054165
```

TABLE3:

```
id_table3        day             town_id_100_coefficent  town_id_200_coefficent 
  1          2020-01-01                 0.011120             0.98556
  2          2020-01-01                 0.023265             0.58467
```

And I need to show output like this:

```
EAN         Day           consumption  
1234     2020-01-01          222.4
5678     2020-01-01         26 121.6
6845     2020-01-01         541.65
```

Output consumtion is calculated by multiplication of coefficient from table 2 with coeficient from table 3 and after that multiplifed coefficent * table 1 consumption.

How to correct join these 3 tables ?
If I join Table 3 to Table 1 date_from and date_to I get bad result (much bigger than may be)

Comment: what is the relation between tables?

Comment: Please create a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with schema and sample data

Comment: Normalize your tables 2 and 3 to `(id, day, attribute, coeff)`.

Comment: Does in `table1` the values of `date_from`, `date_to` are always equal? if not then what rows from tables 2 and 3 must be taken?

Comment: table1 date_from and date_to means connected days.
and table2 and table3 are coefficients of these days
from table 2 and table 3 taking coefficient rows connected on table1 date_from to date_to

Answer (score 0):

to do calculations in your query you can use `SUM`
e.g:

```
SELECT a.ean AS EAN, a.day_from AS Day, SUM(a.consumption*(b.coefficient2*c.coefficient3)) AS consumption, 
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.town_id = b.town_id
LEFT JOIN table3 c ON b.town_id = c.town_id
```

You need to have a relative column in each table to be able to join them, and working with ids are the best in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need conditional(`CASE..WHEN`) statements depending on the values `type` and `region` columns of `table1`, and the third table(`table3`) is not needed. Consider using this query :

```
SELECT t1.ean, t1.date_from AS day, 
       CASE 
       WHEN type = 'blue' 
            THEN 
            CASE 
            WHEN region = 'big' THEN
                 t2.type_blue_big_coefficient * t1.consumption
            WHEN region = 'big2' THEN  
                 t2.type_blue_big2_coefficient * t1.consumption
            END
       WHEN type = 'white' 
            THEN  
                 t2.type_white_coefficient * t1.consumption
        END AS consumption  
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.id_table2 = t1.id_table1
 WHERE t2.day BETWEEN t1.date_from AND t1.date_to
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d0dce61b06937758fcd69190670ae1cf)</kbd>

Comment: Table 3 is needed because coe from table 3 is important for real consumption in that region

Comment: then we don't need table2 @MilanLidmila . Indeed we are able to get the 2 of 3 rows for the expected results without table3 ...

Comment: no..
In table 1 are information about ean - consumption, type, region

In table 2 we have - coe for consumption count

and in table 3 we have - coe for extermination of consumpt to get real consumpt.

So data from all tables are needed..